# LabVIEW Calibration Routine

Tags: calibration, automation, digital-potentiometer

I have a hardware setup where I am trying to null the input offset voltage of an op-amp using an I2C digital potentiometer. The op-amp inputs are shorted and I am measuring the output using an NI Data Acquisition card. Depending on the measured ouput, i want to adjust the offset nulling using the digi pot. I am under pressure to put together a routine to carry out this calibration procedure so I am wondering if anyone has ever done something similar and would be willing to share a pseudo code snippet of how they implemented it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the details of working through the 'unique' interface of LabVIEW, I would suggest using a simple  [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) algorithm.

Set the pot to mid-scale, determine whether the null point lies in the lower or upper half of scale, then set the new upper and lower bounds, and repeat.

Assuming your measurements are stable (you will have to program a delay to allow the op-amp to settle and probably you'll want to average some measurements) it will take one iteration per bit of the result. If your digital pot has 256 steps, it will thus take only 8 iterations to converge on the best setting.

There are potentially faster optimization methods that depend on doing some calculations or that might be better dealing with a very noisy signal (for example fitting a least-square polynomial curve to a number of points and finding the zero), but I think this is more than adequate for the purpose. In fact you could do it several times and compare the results.

This is really a special case of optimization where you are looking to minimize a cost function (the absolute value of the offset or the square of the offset), and with a fairly high cost of evaluating the function (since you have to wait a long time in computer terms for results). Fortunately, it should be fast enough to not be a significant time in human terms.

Comment: I was over-complicating this in my head, binary search will work just fine. Thanks! :)